# Form data should not be modified on POST method through browser inspect

Tags: php-5.5

I have one web application in PHP.
**I have used form POST method on Login. My login data like username and password get visible when i do inspect in firefox browser and even in vulnerability** report. Plz give me solution rather than SSL certificate

Comment: You should really use an SSL. Do you have an examples of your code to review?

Answer (score 0):

The only right way to do that is ssl, since it is encrypted in the protocol. You can get free certificates from https://letsencrypt.org/ and the installation procedure is quite simple.

One WEAK workaround would be to hash the password with a random salt, that you keep in session, for checking the login on the server:

- (server) start a session, generate a random string, (like $_SESSION['salt'] = 'fffgjgjruydhns');
- (server) pass the string to the browser, inside the html;
- (browser) when the user submits the form, hash the password, with the random string, something like sha256(password + randomString)
- (browser) send the hashed string to the server
- (server) checks if the password stored on the server with the salt from the session is the same with the value received from the client: sha256(storedPassword + $_SESSION['salt']) == $_POST['hashedPassword'].

Some important observations about the algorithm above:

- you have to write the actual code, there is no function sha256 in javascript, probably you should use an external library
- the algorithm assumes that you store the user password on the server (and that is not recommended, as you should store a hashed value of it);

Another way of doing it is to implement a public-private sistem, at a application level (server generates a public-private key, sends the public key to the browser, the browser encrypts the password, sends it to the server, the server decrypts it with the private key). But that system will be more difficult to implement than just getting a certificate.

So, first, try to set a normal SSL envoirement, it will help you in the long run.